# AJAX success and failure reporting

Tags: javascript, ajax

Trying to figure out how to report inside this popup only on failure. Currently this works, but it alerts for both success and failure:

```
<script>
function Unlock() {
    var pin=prompt("You must enter pin to unlock");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'pin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {data : pin},
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I have tried the following, but so far with no luck:

```
<script>
function Unlock() {
    var pin=prompt("You must enter pin to unlock");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'pin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {data : pin},
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

*** EDIT ***

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
    $static_password = "1234";
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $submit_password = $_POST['data'];
        if($submit_password == $static_password){
            die("UNLOCK THE RECORD");
        }
        else{
            die("SORRY WRONG PIN");
        }
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Simple AJAX PHP Example</h2>
<a href="javascript:Unlock();">UNLOCK</a>
<p>Pin is "1234"</p>
<script>
function Unlock() {
    var pin=prompt("You must enter pin to unlock");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: 'pin.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {data : pin},
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your server code? It seems like your server is returning a non-20* code

Comment: What response do you see when it is the wrong pin?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **failure**? Empty response or HTTP status code != 200 ?

Comment: just console.log(response),it could be that your recieveing response for both success and error

Comment: Edited original post to include all code. This is the code we just got working. Ideally the popup will only alert the user is the pin is incorrect. If the pin is correct it will just run.

Comment: `die("..")` just outputs a text and terminates the script. It is not considered as failure by client. You have to set HTTP status code to 4xx to tell client about failure.

Comment: That was put in just as an example for time being. Eventually the actual lock, unlock code will be called.

Comment: @Atomiklan in the network inspector, what's the status of the response in both the success and failure cases?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm minutes new to AJAX. Sorry :(

Comment: Here is a live example if it helps: http://www.atomiklan.com/pin.php

Comment: The `error:` callback is usually used for things like network problems or server errors. It's not generally used to detect when the script reports failure in the response.

Comment: When you enter the pin correctly, the idea is for it to just not output anything.

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha, that makes sense.

Comment: You're returning 200 (success) regardless. If the pin is wrong, you should probably return a 403. I think you can do this with `header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');` in the else clause of your conditional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the error callback to be executed, server must respond with status of 404, 500 (internal error), etc. When you write `die('blah');` server responds with a status of 200, and the message that it died with. **This is a successfull request** as far as both AJAX and PHP are concerned.

You have to check the response

```
if($submit_password == $static_password){
    die("UNLOCK THE RECORD");
}
```

then:

```
success: function(response)
    {
       if (response == 'UNLOCK THE RECORD') { /* success */ }
       else { /* failure, do what you will */ }
    }
```

Comment: Sorries Barmar. :)

Comment: Excellent! Looks to give the desired function. Still need to break it down more. Thank you for the help.